# How to access public function from a private function in javascript

Tags: javascript

Here is an example can anybody tell me how to do this

```
var calculation = function(){
    this.Add = function(){
    }
    this.Subtract(){
        var add = function(){
        //want to access Add function here
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use a variable to refer to `this` and you can use that variable latter.

```js
var calculation = function() {
  var _this = this;

  this.Add = function() {
    alert('In Add function');
  }

  this.Subtract = function() {
    var add = function() {
      //want to access Add function here
      _this.Add();
    }
    
    add();
  }
};

var cal = new calculation()
cal.Subtract()
```

Comment: @BhojendraSah, `this.Subtract = function() {` and OPs `this.Subtract(){`

Comment: It would be nice to stick to convention with captialisation of constructor and method names.

Comment: Personally I only would use `var _this = this;` when using this in the function. Otherwise I'll use the bind method. See my answer.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
vvar calculation = function(){
    this.Add = function(){
        alert("test");
    }
    this.Subtract = function(){
        this.Add();
    }.bind(this)
}

var sum = new calculation();
sum.Subtract();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/f6rp9mpL/

Comment: That code is littered with syntax errors, and `bind` is core JavaScript, it doesn't come from jQuery.

Comment: [Function.prototype.bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

Comment: Sorry, did the coding a littlebit too quick. Edited my answer.